# How can I use dependency injection when I use prism IEventAggregator on viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I'm Using Prism on WPF application and I have Viewmodel constructor like

```
...

public TestViewModel(bool bottomPanel, IEventAggregator ea)
{
    __ea = ea;
    IsBottomPanelVisible = bottomPanel;
    OnLoad();
}

...
```

How can I pass parameters to viewmodel in that case?
I want to use something like:

```
Datacontext=new Viewmodels.TestViewModel(true, ...);
```

but I dont know what should be IEventAggregator.
In that case

```
prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
```

in xaml isn't work because shoult pass multiple parameters. How can i solve that issue?

Comment: when using weak events on a class, you cannot pass other parameter.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I pass parameters to viewmodel in that case?

You can't. (*)

The Prism-way of doing this is implementing `INavigationAware` and passing your data in navigation parameters.

--

(*) If you want to you use Prism's navigation, that is. You can always just create your view model in code (through a factory, probably) with whatever constructor parameters you like, and then expose it as a property and bind a data template to it. There's no *need* to start from the xaml, view model-first is very viable, actually.